# Const correctness in C++

Tags: c++, const-correctness

I have simple data structure called `array` (similar to std::array). `array` class have method called `all()`. Here are method declarations:

```
const range<const_type_pointer> all() const;
range<type_point> all();
```

`range` is class template, which is constructed by two iterators. Here is simplified version of `range` class declaration:

```
template <typename Iterator>
class range {

    typedef typename iterator_traits<Iterator>::type_value type_value;
    typedef typename iterator_traits<Iterator>::type_reference type_reference;
    typedef typename iterator_traits<Iterator>::type_pointer;

    range(Iterator begin, Iterator end);
// methods & algorithms

// data members

    mutable Iterator _begin;
    mutable Iterator _end;
};
```

So basically, if I call method all on `const array` object, it should call `const` overload of method and return `const range`. Now, in my algorithms section, I have simple algorithm with following signature:

```
    template <typename UnaryFunction>
    range forEach(UnaryFunction function);
```

Then I tried following test:

```
void test1(const array<int, 10>& array)
{
    auto r = array.all();
    r.forEach([](int i) { std::cout << i << " "; });
}
```

And second one:

```
void test2(const array<int, 10>& array)
{
    auto r = array.all();
    r.forEach([](int& i) { ++i; });
}
```

In first case, where I was just printing variable `i`, compiler did not complained, even though I called non-`const range` method on `const range` object. In second case, compiler complained. Is this behaviour standard confornant?

As a compiler, I am using MSVS compiler.

Comment: as a side note: don't return `const T` (non-reference). It induces subtle bugs and doesn't solve anything. In your case return `range<const_type_pointer>`

Comment: so for example r.forEach([](int i) { std::cout << i << " "; }); won't work? Do you think that it is better solution to have different classes (range & const_range) instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First. Sice you are returning by value, it doesn't really make any difference if you are returning `const range` or `range`.

Second. `auto r = array.all();` creates a copy of whatever was returned by `all`. Your r is a non-const object, and non-const `forEach` is used. But since the iterator is const in the second version, you can't modify the iterable.

Answer (score 1):

`auto` works just like template argument deduction, which means that it drops top-level references and top-level `const` & `volatile` qualifiers. In other words, your `r` is of type `range<const_pointer_type>` in both cases.

Returning a `const`-qualified object should only be done in *very* special circumstances when you understand all details of its behaviour and *really* know that you want them.

Normally, you should just return objects without cv-qualifiers. It will play nicer with move semantics, and will not lead to incorrect expectations.